# How to Select values from relevent specific month in date type?

Tags: sql-server, database

Im new to msSql and i have a set of data about persons. and i need to get results of persons who has birthday in February month.

my DOB fields shows YYYY-MM-DD (1990-02-25)
Can some one please help me to get this results ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: You can get answers easily when you google it. Please post your questions that is technically challenging or needs some research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
SELECT *FROM 
<TableName> 
WHERE month(YourDateColumName)=2
```

Comment: thnks a lot NewUSer :D